# What are the locations of all the hidden/optional tombs?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

I've gotten about half way through Tomb Raider so far I've only managed to find 4 hidden tombs. I want to raid all of these tombs because they each have a ton of scrap and experience in them (Not to mention that they have treasure maps that tell you were other hidden items are in the area) but I'm sure I've missed a few. Anyone figure out where they all are yet?

Comment: [Someone sure has.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8UGzTj8yvWo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, without knowing for sure how detailed of an answer you're seeking, I'm going to list the tombs by location, along with their map coordinates. Excluding DLC, there are 7 optional tombs, and they are:

### Mountain Village

2 Tombs

- ***Tomb of the Unworthy*** 
   53N 712478, UTM 3416188
- ***Hall of Ascension*** 
   53N 712501, UTM 3416206

### Shantytown

2 Tombs

- ***Well of Tears*** 
   53N 712580, UTM 3416067
- ***Chamber of Judgement*** 
   53N 712616, UTM 3416053

### Summit Forest

1 Tomb

- ***Stormguard Sanctum*** 
   53N 712635, UTM 3416007

### Shipwreck Beach

2 Tombs

- ***Temple of the Handmaiden*** 
   53N 712485, UTM 3415986
- ***Flooded Vault*** 
   53N 712521, UTM 3415962

Each tomb will contain either a complete, or partial, treasure map for its respective zone. It will also occasionally contain a part for upgrading one of your weapons. There's no super bonus for completing all 7 of them other than the **Intellectually Superior** achievement/trophy.

You can check out an [interactive version of the map online](http://www.ign.com/maps/tomb-raider/island) to see the location for each of the above more visually. You can filter based on markers to see the tomb entrances.

Comment: Why do you have UTM in between the easting and northing in all the coordinates? I don't think that is standard notation? It would be like writing x,y coordinates of (2,3) as "2, cartesian 3".